# Capturar Top de objeto clicado e aplicar em outro vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Opa, estou criando uma função simples e nela preciso identificar o name do objeto clicado, e a partir daí coletar seu `top`.

```
Private Sub sidebar_bt_all_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sidebar_bt_all.MouseHover
    sidebar_bar_hover_animation.Top = sidebar_bt_all.Top
End Sub
```

No código acima, esta pegando o top do objeto, mas, esta referenciando o objeto diretamente.

O que preciso é que em qualquer botão clicado seja capturado seu .`top` e aplicado no `sidebar_bar_hover_animation`

Answer (score 0):

**Respondendo a sua Pergunta**

Você pode adicionar o codigo abaixo em todos os eventos de click do botão:

```
Dim myButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)
sidebar_bar_hover_animation.Top = myButton.Top
```

**Melhor solução na minha opnião**

Cria-se uma função passando o sender de cada evento do click do botão para ela, e chame esta função dentro de cada evento de click.

```
Private Function GetTop(sender As Object)
    Dim myButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    sidebar_bar_hover_animation.Top = myButton.Top
End Function
```

e chamar na função:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GetTop(sender)
End Sub
```